PC "crashes" all the time
I own a Lenovo ThinkCentre that I believe is an A55 8985-series model but I am not so sure. It has an AMD Athlon CPU from 2005, with 2 GB RAM. I keep swapping the hard drive, none would work. I've tried using SATA and IDE, changing the setting from Slave to Master and Master to Slave, but won't work either way. I'm trying to repair it. It turns on, but I have to face lots of issues. I'm also fixing this PC because I spotted it somewhere in my house. Apparently my dad had it hidden somewhere for 4 or 5 years. When I first fired it up, it would actually turn on, but would give no display since no HDD was present. After that, I don't know what happened, and these problems started to occur:
PROBLEMS:

Sometimes it would start and reach the American Megatrends screen, and try to boot into an OS, but it would BSOD. Always.

If not, it would try to boot into a OS, but would freeze during startup.

If not, it would reach the American Megatrends screen, and freeze, unresponsive. Often times, a row of green lines would appear, and the screen would lightly glitch. The power button would not work in this case, and I would have to just pull the plug out.

If not, it would reach the "ThinkCentre" screen, freeze, and the green lines would appear.

If it is a bad day, the PC would give no display, or not turn on at all unless I leave it off and unattended for hours.

If I try to reinstall an OS, it would either BSOD, or corrupt the files on the USB Drive. It always happens.


The PC wouldn't start before at all, which I suspected was the PSU.
I swapped the 200W PSU with a 250W PSU, and now these problems occur.
SOLUTIONS I TRIED:
I was told that replacing the CMOS Bat. would work, didn't.
Tried booting it without a HDD, fan would just spin at full speed, and power light would occur. If keyboard and mouse are unplugged however, it would beep.
I tried booting it with 1 RAM stick, didn't work. Changed the slots, didn't work. Tried installing a new GPU, didn't work.
No matter what I tried, the PC would just turn on, flash the power light, and the fan would spin at full speed.
From my knowledge however, it powers on when a HDD is present, so I tried replacing the SATA cable, which once again, didn't work.
Is there something I haven't tried?

This has been getting onto my nerves Better stop and evaluate if it's worth your time, money, effort and mental health. The problems you describe suggest a serious problem in the graphics and/or the motherboard.

Well what could go wrong? What's wrong with the GPU or motherboard? As far as I know it has internal graphics and the GPU's I own wouldn't fit.

Physically disconnect all storage drives like HDDs and boot with absolutely minimum components. Does it reach or can you enter BIOS and is it stable over there for a few hours? Or here itself it fails/shuts down/restarts?

"Changing the setting from Slave to Master and Master to Slave" - SATA does not have a Slave or Master setting, so it must be IDE. When you used WinDBG to analysis the BSOD memory dump.  What did the put say was the cause of the crash?

I think often times, a row of green lines would appear, and the screen would lightly glitch already says pretty much everything that we need to know. The iGPU is defective and probably something else in the motherboard. Unless you're a competent electronics engineer to troubleshoot traces, capacitors, etc. you won't find the root cause, end of story. And if you are you wouldn't be here asking and you'd know that very likely you'd spend more than a brand new miniPC 20x more powerful than that old junk.

This https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor_plague , for starters. If you never replaced the capacitors and at least one leaked you can count on a LOT of problems.

The value of a 2005-era computer is very low even when working perfectly.  When it's crashing and costing you time, its value goes negative.  Backup any files you need and transfer them to a computer worth using.

The PC actually came out in Jan 2009 I believe according to a stamp on the casing? It originally came with Windows Vista.

It doesn't change anything @BenVoigt commented above. It's defective, worthless. You may try to sell the salvageable parts, potentially everything BUT the motherboard which is definitely busted! Replacing it is almost impossible (and very expensive even if you can fins a used one in working condition) and repairing it, again, will cost more than new PC that you can actually use and connect to the internet safely. Also be aware of the sunk cost fallacy.

Checked the motherboard - No capacitors are leaking. All of them are completely fine, rust-less. I found one capacitor with a dent and another one with a little bit of lean but otherwise the capacitors are fine.

Please consider rearranging your question following this order: A clear summary of the general problems, a list of the significant specific issues with enough detail that we can clearly understand them, every thing you have tried, why you tried it, and the outcome, a clear statement of your goal. Right now your question is fragmented, disorganized, and confusing. Even through all that though, the commentors are right; Your computer has various, several, and serious hardware faults.  It will be expensive to repair, with a high chance of further issues.
